# Modelling or sculpting mode?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I need your thoughts. Worked on this 50s radio that I found in an antique market yesterday. I'm trying to do a mic to go with it. I've tried every possible shapes, cylinder, Square, stretch, beveled so on and it can't seem to get it. Is that something I would have to go in sculpting mode?

[image]

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots.  The current ones are quite hard to see. Also, please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: This is just my opinion, but things that are hard and polished, like a metal microphone, fall under more of the "hard surface modelling" category than they do the "organic sculpting" category. Therefore, I think the object you are trying to recreate can be done best with basic modelling. You might have to be more intricate with your modelling techniques though.

Comment: As Christopher Bennett says, this is not an object made for sculpting, rather modeling. What part are you struggling with?